# React component getting rerenderd on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My form was working perfectly earlier and now on after few changes the state change the input filed is loosing focus. I am using MUI and it was working earlier perfectly but suddenly it started losing focus after few minor change in state variable names. I think that is not the issue but i don't know why is this happening as all controlled forms are made like this i presume

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Schedule } from "./Schedule";
import { PageHeader } from "./PageHeader";
import { Button, TextField, styled, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import FileUploadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileUpload";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";

function Form() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ startTime: "", endTime: "" });
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [newValue, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  console.log(formData);
  console.log("Rerendered");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setFormData((previousFormData) => {
      return {
        ...previousFormData,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      };
    });
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    setLoading(true);
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const postFormData = new FormData();
      postFormData.append("startTime", formData.startTime);
      postFormData.append("endTime", formData.endTime);
      postFormData.append("date", newValue);
      postFormData.append("file", file);

      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/aip", postFormData, {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "cors",
        },
      })
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .then(setLoading(false))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, 2000);
  }

  const Container = styled("main")({
    marginTop: 50,
    display: "grid",
    justifyItems: "center",
  });
  const Div = styled("div")({
    display: "flex",
    gap: 50,
  });
  const Form = styled("form")({
    border: "none",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    margin: "auto",
    display: "grid",
    justifyItems: "center",
    gap: 50,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader />
      <Container>
        <Form onSubmit={handleClick} encType="multipart/form-data">
          <Div class="timeInput">
            <TextField
              label="From"
              name="startTime"
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="9:00"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={formData.startTime}
              required
            />
            <TextField
              label="To"
              name="endTime"
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="9:30"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={formData.endTime}
              required
            />
          </Div>
          <div class="dateInput">
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DesktopDatePicker
                value={newValue}
                label="Choose Date"
                onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </div>
          <Div>
            <Button sx={{ gap: 2 }} variant="contained" component="label">
              Upload Schedule
              <input
                hidden
                accept=".xlsx"
                multiple
                type="file"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  const file = event.target.files[0];
                  setFile(file);
                }}
              />
              <FileUploadIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button sx={{ gap: 2 }} variant="contained" component="label">
              Search
              <input hidden type="submit" />
              <SendIcon />
            </Button>
          </Div>
        </Form>
      </Container>
      {loading ? (
        <CircularProgress sx={{ alignItems: "center" }} />
      ) : (
        <Schedule data={data} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Would you mind giving us the complete code for your component or at least enough, so we can reproduce?

Comment: Here is the full code of the component

Comment: And does your browser or unit tests throw any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, whenever the react state changes, `App` will re-render. And because `App` re-renders, `Form` gets re-declared and the internal state of the underlying DOM node (`form`) is lost.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const Form = styled("form")({});
  return (
    <Form>
      <input value={value} onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)} />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit quizzical-forest-ti6bb7]

Declare `Form` outside of the body of `App` and it works

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <Form>
      <input value={value} onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)} />
    </Form>
  );
}

const Form = styled("form")({});
```

[image: Edit kind-blackburn-lfj8sd]

If you must declare `Form` in the body of `App` (you probably don't need to), you can memoise it with `React.useMemo`

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const Form = useMemo(() => styled("form")({}), []);
  return (
    <Form>
      <input value={value} onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)} />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react FC inside FC with useMemo]

Answer (score 2):

You should move your styled components outside of the main `Form` component as they are causing re renders. Just note that you will then have clashing names. Styled `Form` and the actual component `Form`. So you will have to either rename the component or the styled `Form`. As to why this happens, I'm not entirely sure but ran into a similar issue before. I assume that every time you type and the state changes, it's re creating the styled components and then re rendering the main component.

```
// Imports
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Schedule } from "./Schedule";
import { PageHeader } from "./PageHeader";
import { Button, TextField, styled, CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import FileUploadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileUpload";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvi/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";

// Styles
const Container = styled("main")({
  marginTop: 50,
  display: "grid",
  justifyItems: "center",
});
const Div = styled("div")({
  display: "flex",
  gap: 50,
});

// Component
const Form = styled("form")({
  border: "none",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  margin: "auto",
  display: "grid",
  justifyItems: "center",
  gap: 50,
});

function Form() {
  // ...
}
export default Form;
```